# Insert Into One Table based on Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I have two tables in ssms that I want the data from one to be put into the other, but i would rather not include some of the data that i have already added.

Table one is data from a particular vendor, it includes an ID and a quantity that i want to grab,

Table Two has the Combined data from all my vendors, where each product has a distinct ID, the quantity, and the units of that quantity (some of our vendors sell in pieces, others Square Footage).

I was trying to use this code:

```
insert into Table2(DistinctID, Quantity,Units)
Select DistinctID, Pieces, 'Pieces' from Table1
Where DistinctID <> Table1.DistinctID
```

however when i run this, no values get added to the table. I am thinking that this is because the statement is looking that the same Distinct ID each time, So then i Thought i would Try to Clarify my Where statement:

```
Where Table2.DistinctID <> Table1.distinctID
```

Except when i do this, i run into the error about a multi-part identifier from table2 cannot be bound.

I am certain that there is a solution to this, but i just don't see what it is. any advice? and if there is anything that i didn't explain well, i will be happy to clarify it, i am relatively new to the Programming game

Comment: What you need to do is write a stand-alone `SELECT` statement that gets you the exact records you need to insert. So you'll need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` statement in your `SELECT` to only grab the records you want to `INSERT`. Then stick the `INSERT INTO ...` bit in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try a NOT EXISTS clause

```
insert into Table2(DistinctID, Quantity, Units)
select t1.DistinctID, t1.Pieces, 'Pieces' from Table1 t1
where not exists 
     (select null 
      from table2 t2 
      where t2.DistinctID = t1.DistinctID)
```

Because in your first attempt, you do`DistinctID <> Table1.DistinctID`. But both `DistinctId` are from `table1` (and a value is never different... from itself).

In the second try, `Table2` is not in the select part, so not known. It's not because it's in the `insert` clause that it's known in the `select` one.

Comment: Nice! that worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

you just solved in 45 seconds what i have been trying to figure for the past day or two!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This will reward Raphaël Althaus for his/her effort and help those that follow you find the answer they are looking for.